# android - menu gui difficulty

Tags: android, user-interface, menu

When I use a simple array that i define in this class, it works fine, but when I call on this string array from my strings.xml, it never seems to work....Any suggestions?  I'm trying to make a menu that lists all the chapter titles

What am I doing wrong???

I'm pretty new to java and android, so please dumb it down as much as possible....Thanks!

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.res.Resources;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ChapterMenu extends ListActivity{

    Resources res= getResources();
    String [] chapterArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.chapters);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChapterMenu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, chapterArray));

    }
```

Comment: Can you check using debug or Log that chapterArray loaded successfully and contains valid data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Resources res= getResources();
        String [] chapterArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.chapters);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChapterMenu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, chapterArray));
    }
```